# C# all common sequences in lists of strings

Tags: c#, list, sorting, sequence

I am trying to find the longest common sequence of strings within the provided arrays.

I have 25,000 lists with sequences, with a total of 450,000 of words that I need to order by length, then by count.

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>() {"Step1", "Step3", "Process", "System", "Process"};
List<string> listB = new List<string>() {"Process", "System", "Process"};
List<string> listC = new List<string>() {"Terminal", "Step1", "Step3"};
...
```

The desired output that prints all possible sequences and their length and count is:

```
Sequence                               Length Count
Step1->Step3->Process->System->Process 5      1
Step1->Step3->Process->System          4      1
Step3->Process->System->Process        4      1
Process->System->Process               3      2
Step1->Step3->Process                  3      1
Step3->Process->System                 3      1
Terminal->Step1->Step3                 3      1
Step1->Step3                           2      2
Process->System                        2      2
System->Process                        2      2
Step3->Process                         2      1
Terminal->Step1                        2      1
Process                                1      4
Step1                                  1      2
Step3                                  1      2
System                                 1      2
Terminal                               1      1
```

I could only find an implementation of substrings, and not whole words that can take multiple lists as input.

Comment: How are you calculating the Count column values?

Comment: If you have a solution for substrings, than you can apply it to this problem by treating the strings in your problem as if they were characters, and your lists as if they were strings

Comment: Do you have to do this only once, or many times? If it's a one-time thing, you could consider loading the data into a database engine (maybe a graph DB) to do it.

Comment: The count is calculated by checking the sequence occurence in all lists. For example "Step1", "Step3" sequence appears twice in all arrays and the length of the sequence is 2.

Comment: What does you input really look like?

Comment: Why isn't `Step1->Step3->Process` a possible sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you can actually overload `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to treat strings like chars in a string. Also it might be reasonable create list segment to prevent flooding runtime with multiple collections.

```
public class ListSegment<T>
{
    private sealed class ListSegmentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ListSegment<T>>
    {
        public bool Equals(ListSegment<T> x, ListSegment<T> y)
        {
            if (x.Length != y.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return x.Lst.Skip(x.Offset).Take(x.Length)
                .SequenceEqual(y.Lst.Skip(y.Offset).Take(y.Length));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ListSegment<T> obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                for (int i = obj.Offset; i < obj.Offset + obj.Length; i++)
                {
                    hash = hash * 31 + obj.Lst[i].GetHashCode();
                }
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<ListSegment<T>> Default { get; } = new ListSegmentEqualityComparer();

    public List<T> Lst { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerable()
    {
        return Lst.Skip(Offset).Take(Length);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join("->", GetEnumerable());
    }
}
```

And then you run through list of lists counting number of occurrences

```
    public List<KeyValuePair<ListSegment<string>, int>> GetOrderedPairs(List<List<string>> data)
    {
        var segmentsDictionary = new Dictionary<ListSegment<string>, int>(ListSegment<string>.Default);
        foreach (var list in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= list.Count; j++)
            {
                var segment = new ListSegment<string>
                {
                    Lst = list,
                    Length = j-i,
                    Offset = i,
                };
                if (segmentsDictionary.TryGetValue(segment, out var val))
                {
                    segmentsDictionary[segment] = val + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    segmentsDictionary[segment] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return segmentsDictionary.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Key.Length).ToList();
    }
```

To test it run following

```
        List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "Step1", "Step3", "Process", "System", "Process" };
        List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "Process", "System", "Process" };
        List<string> listC = new List<string>() { "Terminal", "Step1", "Step3" };
        var pairs = GetOrderedPairs(new List<List<string>>()
        {
            listA, listB, listC
        });
        foreach (var keyValuePair in pairs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key + " " + keyValuePair.Key.Length + " " + keyValuePair.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Good approach and tried to use this but the lst is always the same when I am inspecting it in debugger. When I've added all lists from example into one big list of lists it was always returning "Step1", "Step3", "Process", "System", "Process" sequence.

Comment: updated, a lot of ListSegment contains the same list but with unique offset and length

Answer (score 0):

Using some extension methods, you can create an `IEQualityComparer` that compares `IEnumerable` sequences. Using this, you can use LINQ `Distinct` to compare by sequences:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> DistinctIE<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> src) => src.Distinct(Make.IESequenceEqualityComparer<T>());

    // IEnumerable<string>
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> src, string sep) => String.Join(sep, src);
}

public static class Make {
    public static IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> IESequenceEqualityComparer<T>() => new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T>();
    public static IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> IESequenceEqualityComparer<T>(T _) => new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T>();

    public class IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
        public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) =>
            Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.SequenceEqual(y)));

        public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> src) {
            var hc = new HashCode();
            foreach (var v in src)
                hc.Add(v);
            return hc.ToHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

With these tools, you can create an extension method to generate all the subsequences of a `List` and all the distinct subsequences:

```
public static class ListExt {
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequences<T>(this List<T> src) {
        IEnumerable<T> Helper(int start, int end) {
            for (int j3 = start; j3 <= end; ++j3)
                yield return src[j3];
        }

        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < src.Count; ++j1) {
            for (int j2 = j1; j2 < src.Count; ++j2)
                yield return Helper(j1, j2);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> DistinctSubsequences<T>(this List<T> src) => src.Subsequences().DistinctIE();
}
```

Now you can compute the answer.

First, compute all the subsequences and combine them:

```
var ssA = listA.DistinctSubsequences();
var ssB = listB.DistinctSubsequences();
var ssC = listC.DistinctSubsequences();
var ssAll = ssA.Concat(ssB).Concat(ssC).DistinctIE();
```

Then, create some helpers for counting occurrences:

```
var hA = ssA.ToHashSet(Make.IESequenceEqualityComparer<string>());
var hB = ssB.ToHashSet(Make.IESequenceEqualityComparer<string>());
var hC = ssC.ToHashSet(Make.IESequenceEqualityComparer<string>());

Func<IEnumerable<string>, HashSet<IEnumerable<string>>, int> testIn = (s, h) => h.Contains(s) ? 1 : 0;
Func<IEnumerable<string>,int> countIn = s => testIn(s,hA)+testIn(s,hB)+testIn(s,hC);
```

Finally, compute the answer:

```
var ans = ssAll.Select(ss => new { Sequence = ss.Join("->"), Length = ss.Count(), Count = countIn(ss) }).OrderByDescending(sc => sc.Sequence.Length);
```